# How to calculate score for a particular Tag

Tags: discussion, support, tag-score

Whats the procedure to calculate score for a particular Tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your answers in that tag are selected and the scores of these answers are added up.

Comment: scores of answers means reputation or upvotes ?

Comment: @DonChakkappan Score = upvotes - downvotes

Comment: Ok, but how do I calculate it myself? I want to know how close I am in getting the gold badge for the git tag.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn You can simply see that on your profile. Your score in Git is 492 at the moment.